# PhpStorm 2016.2: How to add theme

Tags: phpstorm

I've tried to add a theme on PhpStorm 2016.2 on MAC (10.9.5)

I've tried to add it on :

- ~/library/.phpStorm2016.1/the_theme.icls
- ~/library/.phpStorm2016.2/the_theme.icls
- ~/library/Preferences/.phpStorm2016.1/the_theme.icls
- ~/library/Preferences/.phpStorm2016.2/the_theme.icls
- ~/library/Preferences/.phpStorm2016.1/colors/the_theme.icls
- ~/library/Preferences/.phpStorm2016.2/colors/the_theme.icls
- ~/library/Preferences/.phpStorm2016.1/config/colors/the_theme.icls
- ~/library/Preferences/.phpStorm2016.2/config/colors/the_theme.icls

Does someone has an idea?

Comment: 1) `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts` 2) Choose any color scheme (e.g. Default or Darcula) and use `Save as..` on it -- give it some unique name (e.g. `ABCDEF`). 3) Now search your user home folder for file with such name.

Comment: As far as I'm aware (not a Mac user here) it should be placed in `~/Library/Preferences/PhpStorm2016.2/colors` folder

Comment: I've tried your solution with a custom name before posting on SO, but i can't find it on my computer :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**for Windows**

Add your theme in directory:

`C:\Users\admin\.PhpStorm2016.2\config\settingsRepository\repository\colors`

Comment: There is no such folder on Windows 10 64bit after fresh install of PhpStorm 2016.2 - `settingsRepository` :(

Comment: He states for mac and you provide for windows!

Answer (score -1):

CTRL+MacKey+G type in "~/Library/Preferences/PhpStorm2016.2/colors"

Put the .icls file in

Answer (score -1):

## Mac

1. Open finder and CMD+SHIFT+G
2. `~/Library/Preferences/PhpStorm2016.2/settingsRepository/repository`
3. create a new folder "**colors**"
4. put the icns files into this folder

## Windows

1. Open explorer and navigate to
2. `C:\Users\yourProfile\.PhpStorm2016.2\config\settingsRepository\repository`
3. create a new folder "**colors**"
4. put the ins files into this folder